# Not able to edit sample invocations in directory listing

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am getting trouble with editing sample invocation name in directory listing and also not able to see previous written sample invocations.My skill got not approved due to following reason
`Your sample invocations are structured incorrectly. Make sure they all begin with "Ok Google", they all contain some reference to your invocation name or display name, and they all trigger one of your actions when said.`

But i'm not able to see previous written sample invocations?
Here is the attached image

[sample invocation showing error in directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEVkv.jpg)

[Previous entered sample invocations is not displaying in directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMDBb.jpg)

Comment: We had a bug in the console. Please take a look again and see if your previous values now appear.

Comment: Thanks @LeonNicholls  its working fine.